# Asynchronous Buffered IO with openmp

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, openmp

I have n threads created by OpenMP that each has to write sequentially into a separate file. 
Thread 0 merges the files into a single file at the end of the computation. 
I was thinking it could be more useful to change this to asynchronously buffered IO (see illustration).
In this solution all n threads are just communicating with a single thread which asynchronous writes into a single file.

I want to know if this approach makes sense and if so, is there a framework that works with OpenMP and supports this approach.

```
         +----------+ +---------+ +----------+
         |          | |         | |          |
         | thread 1 | |  . . .  | | thread n |
         |          | |         | |          |
         +----+-----+ +----+----+ +-----+----+
              |            |            |
              |            | d          |
              |            | a          |
              |            | t          |
              |            | a          |
             +---------------------------+
             |     One thread writes     |
             |   async. buffered IO to   |  
             |       a single File       |
             +---------------------------+
```

Comment: It looks like a simple multiple producers-single consumer problem. There should be many solutions if you just search for it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the right terms. I tried to search for a framework but I just could not find a suitable for this problem.